# Adding HTML label to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've seen the [HighCharts Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels.items.html), and have also [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842123/3191820), but I don't know how to add HTML to the labels. I am trying to create a donut chart with the sum of the values in the middle.

For some reason, this works (**Example A**):

```
var text = this.name + '<br>' + this.y ;
var chart = this.series.chart;
if (!chart.lbl) {
    chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label(text, 140, 110)
        .css({
            fontSize: '22pt',
            textAlign: 'center'
        })
        .add();
} else {
    chart.lbl.attr({
        text: text
    });
}
```

But this does not (**Example B**):

```
var text = '<div><h2>' + this.name + '</h2><p>' + this.y + '</p></div>';
var chart = this.series.chart;
if (!chart.lbl) {
    chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label(text, 140, 110)
        .css({
            fontSize: '22pt',
            textAlign: 'center'
        })
        .add();
} else {
    chart.lbl.attr({
        text: text
    });
}
```

I've tried setting `useHTML` to true:

```
var chartOptions = {
    chart: { ... },
    labels: {
        useHTML: true,
    }
    ...
}
```

But to no avail. Also, the reason **Example A** "works" is that it's creating multiple `<tspan>` elements. Here's the inspect-element on the result from **Example A**:

```
<tspan>Pie 2</tspan>
<tspan>100</tspan>
```

I'd really prefer to get this to use HTML if possible, since that's just easier to style for me, but I *also* need this to be part of the chart, since I need it to interact and change with the chart.

#### EDIT:

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9L5e3q/2/). Click on any of the pie slices to see the effect I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: JSFiddle to play around with would be helpful.

Comment: Please make sure you use the correct properties. `useHtml` is wrong. The correct one is `useHTML`. Please see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.useHTML

Comment: @Ondkloss added the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9L5e3q/2/). @RocoCTZ the `useHtml` was a typo on my part, but using `useHTML` did not change anything. See fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always, when using some inner methods from Highcharts, read how to use them, from the source code:

```
 label: function (str, x, y, shape, anchorX, anchorY, useHTML, baseline, className)
```

As you can see `label()` method has more options, not just only `text`/`x`/`y` ;)

Working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6yQs/57/ , where `useHTML` is set to true.

Comment: Thank you very much. [Here's an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9L5e3q/3/) showing the working result, for anyone else coming across this.

Comment: Just a reminder: `useHTML` doesn't work in when exportingthe chart.

Comment: Pretty much nothing works when exporting charts....

Comment: @Askdesigners - you need to set [`exporting.allowHTML`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML) flag to true, to see HTML elements in the exported chart.

Comment: Oh I just meant that HIghcharts is sadly very coupled to the browser, and doing server rendering is very non-trivial. The supplied render server is an absolute dumpster fire.

Comment: Ouch. Is that related to the rendering engine (PhantomJS, which will be replaced by Headless Chrome, [source](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/roadmap/)), or it's related to the exporting module itself? I mean, rendering a chart and then manually exporting via menu button uses the same exporting server as [exporting server module](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server).